# Sectional jQuery fade breaking after second iteration

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation, delay

So I have the following listener :

```
.on('click', function () {
    if ($('.forum-select-button, .compareToTotal').css('display') == 'none') {
        $('.metric-number, .compareToTotal').each(function (i) {
            $(this).delay((Math.floor(i / (data.columnNames.length + 1)) + 1) * 250).fadeOut('slow', function () {
                $('.forum-select-button').each(function (i) {
                    $(this).delay((Math.floor(i / (data.columnNames.length + 1)) + 1) * 250).fadeIn('slow');
                });
            });
        });
    } else {
        $('.forum-select-button').each(function (i) {
            $(this).delay((Math.floor(i / (data.columnNames.length + 1)) + 1) * 250).fadeOut('slow', function () {
                $('.metric-number, .compareToTotal').each(function (i) {
                    $(this).delay((Math.floor(i / (data.columnNames.length + 1)) + 1) * 250).fadeIn('slow');
                });
            });
        });
    }
})
```

The `forum-select-button` buttons are set to `display:none` by default, and the `metric-number` and `compareToTotal` one's are set to `display:block`. The first set works, as in the numbers fade away and the buttons appear, but if you click the button a second time, there will be a long pause, the numbers will re-appear and VERY slowly the buttons will re-appear. Changing the delay doesn't seem to do anything.

Comment: What's that `.bind(section)`?

Comment: What effect do you want to happen? Do you want the `forum-select-button`'s to appear when the `metric-number` and `compareToTotal`s are disappearing, or do you want them to appear after they are all gone?

Comment: @falsarella That's actually remnants from the last function that was within this onclick listener. I've removed it, and I'll edit the post.

Comment: @Stryner Yea exactly, I'd like the row's metric-number and compareToTotal to disappear, and the forum-select-button to appear, then the same for the next row, until all rows are done. And this works for my first click, but it seems the first delay on the 2nd call is breaking everything.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up fixing it by writing out delay in favor of setTimeout. Here is my solution:

```
.on('click', function(){
    if($('.forum-select-button, .compareToTotal').css('display') == 'none'){
        $('.metric-number, .compareToTotal').each(function(i){
            setTimeout(function(){
                $(this).fadeOut('slow', function(){
                    $('.forum-select-button').each(function(i){
                        setTimeout(function(){
                            $(this).fadeIn('slow');
                        }.bind(this), (Math.floor(i / (data.columnNames.length + 1)) + 1) * 250);
                    });
                });
            }.bind(this), (Math.floor(i / (data.columnNames.length + 1)) + 1) * 250);
        });
    } else {
        $('.forum-select-button').each(function(i){
            setTimeout(function(){
                $(this).fadeOut('slow', function(){
                    $('.metric-number, .compareToTotal').each(function(i){
                        setTimeout(function(){
                            $(this).fadeIn('slow');
                        }.bind(this), (Math.floor(i / (data.columnNames.length + 1)) + 1) * 250);
                    });
                });
            }.bind(this), (Math.floor(i / (data.columnNames.length + 1)) + 1) * 250);
        });
    }
})
```

Works like a charm :)